# HTML table with dynamic rows populated by 2 mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Brief look at what I want to accomplish]

Above is a brief idea of what I want to do.To simply get the fee type and amount on the fee item in order of priority.Ignoring fee type items that have already been paid for or covered.
I have 3 tables in my [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/462fc/9) :

1. fee_payments contains amounts paid,to be captured in the screenshot column C
2. Fee_types is what is to be captured in the screenshot column B.The fee_types have priority such that payments made should reflect starting with the highest priority B.E.S up till where amount ends.
3. Fees Periods specifies the Term/Period paid.

If previous payment already covered the 1st few items then it should start from current item.
**Example scenario.** If 550 was paid initially  and 400 paid now it should start at L.t.t. with amount 20, E.W.C 200,R.M.I 180.Because B.E.S 250 and a part of LTT of 300 is already paid for

This is my html and php code attempt

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT t.type,p.amount as payable FROM fee_types t INNER JOIN  fee_periods p ON t.feetype_id = p.feetype_id 
    WHERE p.term_name='Term 1' AND p.class_for='Class 1' order by t.type_priority ASC ";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Cannot get Info7.');
$row5    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row5);

$sql = "SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( pay_date,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS pay_date FROM fees_payment WHERE adminNo =  '$adminNo' AND term_id =  '$term_id'
       ORDER BY pay_id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Cannot get Info.');
?>

 <table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="5%"><strong>ID</strong></td>      
        <td width="42.5%"><strong>Fee Type</strong></td>
        <td width="42.5%"><strong>Amount</strong></td>            
     </tr>
 <?php
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           extract($row);
       if ($i%2) {
          $class = 'row1';
          } else {
          $class = 'row2';
           }
     $i += 1;
?>
          <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td><?php if ($payable<$amount) {echo $type;} ?></td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($amount,2);?></td>
       </tr>
<?php
  }
}
else{
echo 'No Details for now.';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: This is to be used for a school fee receipt.Where fees are paid in order of priority eg. tuition before food and accomodation.So if you were to pay just part of the fee.It should show the 1st fee item Tuition then the 2nd up to where your paid amount can cover.Also if you had already made an earler payment it will check the amount and after comparing start from where it was left off @satchcoder

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it.
Have a table structure as this

```
student_details(id,name,class..)//student table

fee_terms(term_id,class,total_fee)//Entry for fees to be paid by student in that class

fee_term_specifics(item_id,total_amount,term_id)//items paid for in that term

student_payments(stud_id,item_id,amt_paid,date_paid)//Store student payments
```

During entering of fee payments the clerk selects a student and the system generates a list the items not paid by student and their balance.(A join of fee_term_specifics & student_payments).

Let the clerk enter the total amount the student has paid upon which the system distributes the amount to the specific item until the paid amount is exhausted.

**NB::** The clerk should be able alter the distibution.

Upon submission of form save the data in the student_payments table.

**Hint::** Have a form with inputs for all the payment types but only display for those not yet paid for. You can use a javascript method to distribute the students payment depending on item weight. Also have a way to handle situations of excess payments. You can have an item type called excess-payment that is filled last.

Comment: Interesting approach.Definitely seems easier than coming up with some function to compare the 2 queries and display an output.Will give it a try.